# Cannot set Textview text from database resultset

Tags: java, android

Cannot set **Textview** text from database resultset. There is no error but **textview** text is not updating. Also any **textbox** inside the code block after query, not setting the value dynamically. why does it seem to be skipping the "try" clause entirely?

Here is my code

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            connectionClass = new ConnectionClass(); //the class file
            tripid=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tripid);           
            tripname();
    }
    private void tripname() {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {

                } else {
                    String query = "select * from tblTrip where TripId ='" + tripid+ "'";
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                    name = rs.getString(2);
                    TextView tripname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tripname);
                    tripname .setText(name);

     TextView name= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                    name .setText("tri");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Error " + ex.getMessage());
            }


        }
```

Comment: Probably you try to update view inside a background thread. You have to do it from UI thread. Add more details of that class to investigate

Comment: did you received any exception(Exception ex)

Comment: no. i didn't receive any exception. just textview text is not setting dynamically inside the code block after query. but if i set value to the textview after catch block it works.

Comment: What is your `ConnectionClass` do?

Comment: Connect to database using net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Comment: How can i set the text from resultset?

Comment: Mind your data types - they are meaningful: I suppose TripID is an integer in your table (as it actually ***should be***). But you are searching a string. Then it simply  ***can't compare*** it.

Comment: You shouldn't be using JDBC drivers directly in Android

Comment: why does it seem to be skipping the "try" clause entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Maby you can get database resultset in a background thread,then you have to update date from UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

`TripId ='" + tripid+ "'` is adding the TextView's object representation to the query.

1) Use PreparedStatement properly with question marks, not String concatenation
2) use tripid.getText() to get the displayed string